# Is there a way to enable Javascript on bulkEdit form from Dynamics 365 CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Multiple required fields from bulk edit form are not displayed. The labels for that fields appear on form but the textboxes don't appear. I think this happens because we have scripts that run for that fields. I tried to edit `customizations.xml` and to put `BehaviorInBulkEditForm = "Enabled"` but it is not working. Is there another way to enable javascript?

Comment: welcome. Can you share code so we can reproduce somehow?

Comment: Is that editing xml solution is still supported ?

Comment: It appears to not be supported anymore, but I still tried it. :) There are multiple scripts for onload and on save on main form for some business logic( like concatenate last name and first name into full name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to stay away from unsupported customizations which will eventually break in future updates.

If it’s worth, then move all the logic to post-update or pre-update plugins which is fail proof server side implementation rather than client side js route.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Form XML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/form-xml-schema), the `BehaviorInBulkEditForm` attribute goes on the `<event>` element, careful you're not putting it somewhere else.

The valid values, as per [Microsoft KB 949941](https://web.archive.org/web/20141228115338/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949941), are:

> **Enabled**
> If you use this value, the field is enabled. Additionally, the code for the event is run when the event is called.
>
> **Disabled**
> If you use this value, the field is disabled.
>
> **EnabledButNoRender**
> If you use this value, the field is enabled. However, the code for the event is not run when the event is called.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the new Wave 2021 Update no longer respects this flag. So even though its in the schema, it doesn't do anything anymore.

Which in all honestly is really stupid considering that getFormType (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui/getformtype) specifically has a return code for "Bulk Edit" (6). But there is absolutely no way to turn on the JavaScript to even run the API. So its basically useless.

Comment: oh no. Guess this is caused by 2021 Wave 2's [upgrade of bulk edit forms to the UCI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2021wave2/power-apps/new-model-driven-app-experience-editing-multiple-records). Might put a support ticket in to check this was intentional / get the docs updated.

Comment: Update: I just did a test upgrade to 2021 wave 2 and my client script seems to be running and working correctly in the new UCI bulk edit form. So I'm not sure what @killerrin is seeing.

Comment: We just updated couple different of our environments to the new 2021 Wave 2 and all of the UCI Bulk Edit forms across all of them are no longer running JS using the "BehaviorInBulkEditForm=Enabled" method on an OnLoad function

Comment: @killerrin how unsettling! Have you raised a support case? [Here is my formxml](https://gist.github.com/fowl2/4a6f7d6810b149c877bf99fd51768046), perhaps you can spot something?

Comment: @Foul no Support case. Microsoft is just going to come back and tell us its "Unsupported" as has happened in the past.

That said, your FormXml and how we have it enabled is pretty much identical to ours. Only thing I can think of is our web resources have dependencies on other Web Resources, however that was an issue that was solved previously by just including the other web resources on the form and enabling those to run in the Bulk Edit as well

Comment: @killerrin [FormXml customization is explicitly supported as long as the schema is followed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/supported-customizations#:~:text=Form%20and%20dashboard%20customization%20using%20FormXml). (Also, ouch I hope I'm not 'foul' ;))

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding the flag, and it is working perfectly.  I guess Microsoft fixed the issue.  Let's hope it persists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).